# Is it a good idea to centralize layout for multiple corporate websites?

Tags: html, css, image, layout

I work for a customer in The Netherlands and I was wondering if it is a good idea to centralize layout for all websites in one place.

The customer has a large setup with hundreds of intra-/extra- and internet websites used by students, teachers and personnel across multiple locations. They would like to see that all sites have the same look-and-feel and of course corporate layout.

We mainly use .Net MVC with for each site local layout. There is a corporate layout but it is copied to each site individually. Any changes in the corporate layout would have to be implemented in each site. There is a large server farm with all the needed hardware like firewalls, loadbalancers, webservers, databaseservers, etc. Lots of virtualization too.

If it is a good idea how does one set this up?

Comment: I think we would need more information in order to answer. How are the sites currently developed?

Comment: We mainly use .Net MVC with for each site local layout. There is a corporate layout but it is copied to each site individually. Any changes in the corporate layout would have to be implemented in each site. There is a large server farm with all the needed hardware like firewalls, loadbalancers, webservers, databaseservers, etc. Lots of virtualization too.

Answer (score 1):

We have achieved this in the past using a common DLL that is shared with all the other sites.  Two techniques were used to accomplish this.

One, use [Razor Generator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorGenerator.Mvc/).  This will compile any views you want to share in this DLL to `.cs` files.

Two, you'll also probably want to share images, javascript, and other content between all these sites, and to achieve that you can using [embedded resources](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB695GB695&ei=4LEwXfS1OJGW1fAP8NCumAQ&q=C%23%20embedded%20resource%20MVC&oq=C%23%20embedded%20resource%20MVC&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i22i29i30l5.11362.15650..15954...3.0..1.113.1700.28j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j35i39j0i67j0i131j0j0i131i67j0i13j33i21j33i160j0i22i30.UcTImvDU3ik&ved=0ahUKEwj0pdmxhL_jAhURSxUIHXCoC0MQ4dUDCAo&uact=5).

Comment: We are not trying to share views across websites. Can we create masterpages that could be used in views this way? The second suggestion also crossed my mind as a solution.

Comment: @PaulSinnema Yes, absolutely - you can have layouts in your "common" DLL (that get compiled via the Razor Generator), in fact in my project, that's the most common use-case is the main layout is used by every other internal application.

Answer (score 0):

From what you say, it sounds like it's a good idea, because it'll save you an effort of copying updates to each project every time.

If you arrange your styles in a SCSS manner (eg. 7-1 pattern https://link.medium.com/pvUkbtLFqY), you can use components in whatever mixture you prefer. I even heard about possibility to turn particular SCSS dependencies into npm packages with x.x.x version control.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with SASS. I'll have to dive in to understand what you're suggesting.